# Oracle Workflow Message Attribute as respond

Tags: workflow

I have created lookup type and lookup values for my workflow itemtype using `wf_lookup_types_pkg.insert_row`

and inserted `lookup_codes` using `wf_lookups_pkg.insert_row`.

But I am unable to connect it from `plsql`.

How can I create a lookup type as an attribute in worfklow.

Comment: Kindly post what you have coded till now and mention where the issue is in the code.

Comment: I did not find any API to attach created lookup to attribute.
What i have done is using wf_lookup_types_pkg.insert_row this API i created one lookup for my workflow, then using wf_lookups_pkg.insert_row API i inserted values to lookup code. But i am unable to attach it in workflow attribute.
for example if i want to create text attribute in oracle workflow i use 
wf_engine.setitemattrtext(itemtype,itemkey,aname,avalue) API ,but in case of lookup there is no such API. So in this case what should i do?

Comment: @sanketkatariya please use the edit button at the bottom left of your post to add additional information to your question. Comments tend to get deleted now and then causing this information to get lost.

Comment: Formatting and grammar